# Is there a word referring to something that motivates you?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, vocabulary, colloquial-language

One of my pupils wanted to express that there is a song that gives him motivation to create things. He referred to the song as a "kicker". I looked the word kicker up and the OED says it refers to something unexpected but not motivating as such. What word would you use in the context?

Answer (score 1):

**Inspiration**.

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=inspiration

> 2. A person or thing that moves the intellect or emotions or prompts action or invention: Gandhi has been an inspiration to political reformers for decades.

Comment: Inspiration. Good. I am curious about whether there is a colloquial version of the word too.

Answer (score 0):

**Muse**

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muse

2. A source of inspiration.